# Mongoose update loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I'm new to the world of mongoose and NodeJs, my problem occurs when I perform an update, effectively the update is carried out in the database but time later it happens again.

I perform the update as follows

```
router.post("/deleteLead", (req, res) => {
          console.log("----------- delete lead -------");
          const body = req.body;
          deleteLead(body);
});


  async function deleteLead(body) {
              const id_delete = body.leads.delete[0].id;
              const deleteLead = await Model_Lead.updateOne(
                { id: id_delete },
                {
                        is_deleted: true,
                }
              );
              console.log(deleteLead);
    };
```

this is the log of my aplication when i update a lead

```
----------- delete Lead -------
{
  acknowledged: true,
  modifiedCount: 1,
  upsertedId: null,
  upsertedCount: 0,
  matchedCount: 1
}
{
  acknowledged: true,
  modifiedCount: 1,
  upsertedId: null,
  upsertedCount: 0,
  matchedCount: 1
}
----------- delete  Lead -------
{
  acknowledged: true,
  modifiedCount: 1,
  upsertedId: null,
  upsertedCount: 0,
  matchedCount: 1
}
----------- delete  Lead -------
{
  acknowledged: true,
  modifiedCount: 1,
  upsertedId: null,
  upsertedCount: 0,
  matchedCount: 1
}
----------- delete Lead -------
{
  acknowledged: true,
  modifiedCount: 1,
  upsertedId: null,
  upsertedCount: 0,
  matchedCount: 1
}
```

Comment: Please share more of your code, specifically the code which calls `deleteLead` and logs `update Lead`.

Comment: You should also end the response, for example, `res.send(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

You're not awaiting the result of your `deleteLead` call. This means that your controller will just send off the request and move on.

When the request does resolve, it may happen while another controller is in the process of running, which would result in query results being logged in a way that *looks like* your controller hit MongoDB more than once, when it actually didn't.

Comment: How can i add the await in that call ?

Comment: The same way that you're awaiting the result of your MongoDB query.

Comment: like this ?
```
router.post("/deleteLead", (req, res) => {
          console.log("----------- delete lead -------");
          const body = req.body;
          await deleteLead(body);
});
```

Comment: Yes, but you'll likely get an error that `await` is being used inside of a non-async function. You'll also need to label your arrow function as `async` the same way you did for `deleteLead`.